# Add address at end of line in hosts file using sed

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sed

I have a specific line in the hosts file that is used for my local Wordpress Multisite install, which looks like this:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost domain.dev site1.domain.dev site2.domain.dev
```

I'm writing a Shell script that I can run to create a new individual site on my Multisite install straight from Terminal. I need to be able to add a new record to my /etc/hosts file whenever I run this command. In the Shell file, I'm using `$site_addr` as my variable for the site name. You then need to add .domain.dev to the end of this. An example I've done (which didn't work) using sed:

```
sed -i'.bak' '7i7 $site_addr.domain.dev' /etc/hosts
```

Yhe line from my hosts file (above) that I need to edit is line 7, hence the `7i7` in the sed command. I want to add the new record at the end of the line. I also want to create a backup hosts file in case anything goes wrong.

Thanks for any help guys, hope i've explained it well enough :)

Comment: Use __double quotes__.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if this is the line 7

```
sed -i '.bak' "7 s/$/ ${site_addr}.domain.dev/" /etc/hosts
```

but you can use the pattern matching (a bit safer) with

```
sed -i '.bak' "/127\.0\.0\.1/ s/$/ ${site_addr}.domain.dev/" /etc/hosts
```

i recommend to also first check if the domain is not already in

Comment: the second one works, but it just inserts `${site_addr}.domain.dev` instead of the variable that I assign in Terminal using the read -p command, e.g `read -p "Enter site address: " site_addr`. If i remove the parentheses (`$site_addr.domain.dev`), it just inserts that. Does the variable need to be escaped or something?

Comment: As @devnull mentioned under the question... Use double qoutes... Variables are not expanded inside single quotes.

Comment: sorry, too fast when editing. Sur double quote due to $site interpretation, sorry, i do the correction

Comment: ah that worked with the double quotes, thanks guys :)